# A proof in Janusz Algebraic Number Field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I can't understand Lemma 6.2 from the Janusz book *Algebraic number fields*, pag. 26, that says:

Let $A\subset B$ be integral domains with $A$ integrally closed and $B$ integral over $A$. If $\mathfrak{P}$ is a nonzero prime ideal of $B$, then $\mathfrak{P}\cap A$ is a nonzero prime ideal of $A$.

**proof.** Take an element $x\in\mathfrak{P},x\neq 0$ and let
$$f(t)=a_0+a_1t+\ldots+a_rt^r+t^{r+1}$$
be the minimum polynomial of $x$ over the quotient field of $A$. $\textbf{Since $B$ is integral over $A$ and $A$ is integrally closed, we know that $a_i$ lie in $A$...}$

what follows is completely clear to me, while i can't understand the bold part, thanks for any help

Comment: You have it there, @Federica: it is in lemma 2.4 !

Comment: @DonAntonio but i can't see it, lemma 2.4 is about transitivity of integral dependence, here i have only $B$ integral over $A$. If i could say that $a_i$ lie in $B$, then.....ok

Comment: BTW, this is a classical commutative-algebraic theorem, so have a look at the book by $Atiyah-Macdonald$. Per chance you will find it clearer and more inspiring. Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The element $\,x\,$ is algebraic over the fraction field of $\,A\,$ , say $\,\Bbb F_A\,$

(2) As shown in lemma $\,2.4\,$ , all the conjugates of $\,x\,$ (= all the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\,x\,$ over\,$\;\Bbb F_A\,$) are also algebraic, and if $\,x\,$ is *integral* over $\,A\,$ (as is our case) then its conjugates are integral, too.

(3) Since the coefficients of $\,f(t)\,$ are symmetric polynomials in $\,x\,$ and its conjugates they are *also* integral over $\,A\,$ ...

Comment: maybe it is too difficult for me, or i'm missing something...$x$ is in $\mathfrak{P}$, which is in $B$, which is integral over $A$, so $x$ is integral over $A$. Why do the other roots of $f$ should be integral over $A$?...I can't see how to apply lemma 2.4

Comment: @FedericaMaggioni , do you know that the set of all integral elements in some ring over some other ring is...a ring? This is corollary to proposition 2.2 in Janusz.

Comment: yes i know that, what i don't know is why the roots of $f$ conjugates of $x$ are integral too

Comment: Oh, because they are roots of the same monic pol. over $\,A\,$ as $\,x\,$ !

Comment: but the polynomial is not over $A$, it has coefficients in $F_A$.

Comment: But if $\,x\,$ is integral then the coefficients are **in fact** in $\,A\,$...just think of what happens with $\,\Bbb Z\,,\,\Bbb Q\,$: if you take an alg. number which is **also** integral over $\,\Bbb Z\,$ then its minimal pol. (over $\,\Bbb Q\,$ !) is *in fact* in $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ ...Why is this? Because $\,\Bbb Z\,$ is int. **closed**, just like our $\,A\,$ in this question.